# variable assigned to anonymous function is not defined

Tags: javascript, global, anonymous

I am using anonymous function assigned to a variable to minimize use of global variables. Within this function there are nested functions: one to preload and resize images, and two other nested functions for navigation (next and previous). The code below generates error that the variable to which the anonymous function is assigned is not defined:
**Cannot read property 'preload_and_resize' of undefined**
 If you spot the problem please let me know. Thank you very much.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var runThisCode=(function(){
 var myImages=new Array("img/01.jpg","img/02.jpg","img/03.jpg");
 var imageObj = new Array();
 var index=0;
 var preload_and_resize=function(){
        var i = 0;
        var imageArray = new Array();
        for(i=0; i<myImages.length; i++) {
            imageObj[i] = new Image();
            imageObj[i].src=myImages[i];
        }

    document.pic.style.height=(document.body.clientHeight)*0.95;
};
 var next_image=function(){
    index++;
    if(index<imageObj.length){
        document.pic.src=imageObj[index].src;
    }
    else{
        index=0;
        document.pic.src=imageObj[index].src;
    }
 };
 var prev_image=function(){
    index--;
    if(index>=0){
        document.pic.src=imageObj[index].src;
    }
    else{
        index=myImages.length-1;
        document.pic.src=imageObj[index].src;
    }
 };
})();
</script>
</head>
<body onload="runThisCode.preload_and_resize();">
<div align="center">
<img name="pic" id="pic" src="img/01.jpg"><br />
<a href="JavaScript:runThisCode.prev_image()">Prev</a><a href="JavaScript:runThisCode.next_image()">Next</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your anonymous function doesn't return anything, so when you run it, undefined gets returned.  That's why `runThisCode` is undefined.  Regardless though, with the way you've written it, `preload_and_resize` will be **local**, so you wouldn't be able to access that anyway.

Instead, you want this anonymous function to construct an *object*, and reutrn **that**.  Something like this should work, or at least get you close:

```
var runThisCode=(function(){
 var result = {};
 result.myImages=new Array("img/01.jpg","img/02.jpg","img/03.jpg");
 result.imageObj = new Array();
 result.index=0;
 result.preload_and_resize=function(){
        var i = 0;
        var imageArray = new Array();
        for(i=0; i< result.myImages.length; i++) {
            imageObj[i] = new Image();
            imageObj[i].src=myImages[i];
        }

    document.pic.style.height=(document.body.clientHeight)*0.95;
};
 result.next_image=function(){
    index++;
    if(index<imageObj.length){
        document.pic.src=imageObj[index].src;
    }
    else{
        index=0;
        document.pic.src=imageObj[index].src;
    }
 };
 result.prev_image=function(){
    index--;
    if(index>=0){
        document.pic.src=imageObj[index].src;
    }
    else{
        index=myImages.length-1;
        document.pic.src=imageObj[index].src;
    }
 };

 return result;
})();
```

Comment: @Adam Thank you, Adam. This was my clumsy attempt to avoid global vars as in *var myImages=new Array("img//01.jpg","img//02.jpg","img/03.jpg");
 var imageObj = new Array();
 var index=0;* I will try to fix it based on your help.

Comment: @Neil: You can keep the Arrays and index private and just expose the functions if you want. Adam Rackis: +1.

Comment: @Neil - yes, I made everything public in my code.  Declaring something as var within that function will make it local (private).  The result object will have access to it, but not the outside world

Answer (score 2):

This should explain what you are doing wrong :

```
var foobar = (function (){
   var priv1, priv2 = 'sum' , etc;
   return {
      pub_function: function() {},
      another: function() {
          console.log('cogito ergo ' + priv2 );
      }
   };

})();

foobar.another();
```

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned the function to the variable `next_image` which is scoped to the self-invoking anonymous function.

The value you assign to `runThisCode` is the return value of that anonymous function, which (since there is no `return` statement) is `undefined`.

To get the code to work you need to assign an object to `runThisCode` and make `next_image` a member of it.

Add the following to the end of the anonymous function:

```
return {
    "next_image": next_image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the anonymous function, and make your function public. You will only create one global variable: the object `runThisCode`.

```
var runThisCode = function () {
    var myImages = new Array("img/01.jpg", "img/02.jpg", "img/03.jpg");
    var imageObj = new Array();
    var index = 0;
    this.preload_and_resize = function () {
        var i = 0;
        var imageArray = new Array();
        for (i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++) {
            imageObj[i] = new Image();
            imageObj[i].src = myImages[i];
        }

        document.pic.style.height = (document.body.clientHeight) * 0.95;
    };
    this.next_image = function () {
        index++;
        if (index < imageObj.length) {
            document.pic.src = imageObj[index].src;
        } else {
            index = 0;
            document.pic.src = imageObj[index].src;
        }
    };
    this.prev_image = function () {
        index--;
        if (index >= 0) {
            document.pic.src = imageObj[index].src;
        } else {
            index = myImages.length - 1;
            document.pic.src = imageObj[index].src;
        }
    };
};
```

And then, later in your code:

```
runThisCode.preload_and_resize();
```

should work.

Comment: i guess you have no clue what **closures** in javascript are.

Comment: To use properties like that, you'd need to invoke `runThisCode` as a constructor like this: `(new runThisCode).preload_and_resize()`, but then you're not capturing the returned object, so you wouldn't have access to the other methods unless you run the constructor again. This would be undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

From the invocation you've got in body onload property, it looks like what you're trying to achieve with the IIFE ([immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)) is return an object that has a the method `preload_and_resize`.

As others have pointed out, you're not returning anything from the IIFE, so really all that's happening is you're closing up everything inside it in its own namespace, but not "exporting" anything.

If you want to "export" those functions, from your IIFE, you'd probably add a final bit to it that looked something like this:

```
return { 
    'preload_and_resize': preload_and_resize, 
    'next_image': next_image,
    'prev_image': prev_image
}
```

which essentially creates a new JavaScript object literal, and then assigns its properties to the function values from the local scope.

Some developers would find this redundant and rather than finishing out with this sort of explicit export would probably just define the functions while declaring the object literal, something like:

```
return { 
    preload_and_resize: function(){
        var i = 0;
        var imageArray = new Array();
        for(i=0; i<myImages.length; i++) {
            imageObj[i] = new Image();
            imageObj[i].src=myImages[i];
        }

        document.pic.style.height=(document.body.clientHeight)*0.95;
    },
    next_image: function() {
        index++;
        if(index<imageObj.length){
            document.pic.src=imageObj[index].src;
        }
        else {
            index=0;
            document.pic.src=imageObj[index].src;
        }
    },
    prev_image: function() {
        index--;
        if(index>=0){
            document.pic.src=imageObj[index].src;
        }
        else {
            index=myImages.length-1;
            document.pic.src=imageObj[index].src;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Adam,@SLaks,@RightSaidFred,@mc10,@Weston C,@Quentin  Thank you all very much. As you suggested I added a return statement - that was the most important thing that I missed! - and that worked. I made the anonymous function return a literal object with three properties one for each var to which respective nested function is assigned, but now reading your comments and code there is some redundancy and ugliness I can clear up from my code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In respect of previous answers, my version:

```
function(self) {
    let myImages = new Array("img/01.jpg", "img/02.jpg", "img/03.jpg");
    let imageObj = new Array();
    let index = 0; // if you need to expose this call with self.index

    self.preload_and_resize = function() {
        let i = 0;
        let imageArray = new Array();
        let (i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++) {
            imageObj[i] = new Image();
            imageObj[i].src = myImages[i];
        }
        document.pic.style.height = (document.body.clientHeight) * 0.95;
    };
  
    var next_image = function() {
        index++;
        if (index < imageObj.length) {
            document.pic.src = imageObj[index].src;
        } else {
            index = 0;
            document.pic.src = imageObj[index].src;
        }
    };
  
    var prev_image = function() {
        index--;
        if (index >= 0) {
            document.pic.src = imageObj[index].src;
        } else {
            index = myImages.length - 1;
            document.pic.src = imageObj[index].src;
        }
    };
})(window.myCurrentPage = window.myCurrentPage || {});

// now you canll myCurrentPage.preload_and_resize();
```